# Ruby: How do I close a file after calling it in script

Tags: ruby

Using the below script, where would the close() syntax go and what would it be?

```
print "Enter the filename you want to open here > "
filename = $stdin.gets.chomp
txt = open(filename)

puts "Here's your file #{filename}"
print txt.read
print "Type the filename again: "

file_again = $stdin.gets.chomp
txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has two abilities: explicitly call [`IO#close`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-close) within `ensure` block or use a block version of [`IO#read` / `open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-read):

```
filename = $stdin.gets.chomp
begin
  txt = open(filename)
  puts "Here's your file #{filename}"
  print txt.read
ensure
  txt.close
end


filename = $stdin.gets.chomp
open(filename) do |txt|
  puts "Here's your file #{filename}"
  print txt.read
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the close method, in your context: `txt.close`

But I recommend you to use blocks, so your code will be better

Something like this

```
File.open(filename) do |txt|
   ...
   print txt.read
   ...
end
```